# Difference between Static and StaticString

Tags: ios, swift, static

I confuse with

> **static** var str = "Hello1"

> var str2: **StaticString** = "Hello2"

What is the best case to use **StaticString**?

How is **static** and **StaticString** allocate memory?

Answer (score 1):

static string can be known at the compile time.

```
let str1: String = "str1" // ok
let str2: String = "\(str1) + 1" // ok
let str3: StaticString = "\(str1)" // illegal
```

StaticString has to be known.

```
let foo: StaticString = "foo" // ok
```

personally, i have only seen this used when creating some sort of a signpost functionality to test performance on the instruments